# Client_side_validation not working after installing nested_form gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, client-side-validation

I am using client_side_validations gem for inline validations. This was working fine until I installed nested_form gem for adding multiple images. Now the **inline validations is not showing up errors**.

In application.js I have

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require twitter/bootstrap
    //= require_self
    //= require_tree .
    //= require jquery_nested_form
```

In application.html.erb file I have

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>      
     <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "rails.validations" %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "nested_form" %>
```

In _form.html.erb I have this code

```
    <%= nested_form_for(@project, :html => {:multipart => true }, :validate => true) do |f| %>
```

I'm not able to understand where I  went wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: try using simple_form. that might help you

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to have

```
//= require rails.validations
```

in the application.js